# Tensorflow tutorial + How to extract classes and probability from generator object

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, mnist

The code in the MNIST tensorflow [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers) creates a dictionary of classes and probabilities and it returns an EstimatorSpec object,

```
predictions = {
    "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
    "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
}
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)
```

Output is in the following form:

```
....
{'class_ids': 1, 'logits': array([-32976400., -30171870.], dtype=float32)}
{'class_ids': 1, 'logits': array([-32958380., -30386898.], dtype=float32)}
{'class_ids': 1, 'logits': array([-32940332., -30601930.], dtype=float32)}
{'class_ids': 1, 'logits': array([-32922300., -30816956.], dtype=float32)}
....
```

**Question:** How can I access and retrieve these class_id values in a loop?
I'm trying to count the number of correctly classified classes by equating these predicted class ids with their original value. How can I achieve this?

This is what I was trying.

```
 ##pred_results contains the EstimatorSpec object
  for i in range(0,len(FileList)):
    x=FileList[i].split('\\')[5]        # This gives me the actual class ID
    print(x+"\nProbability:")
    print(next(pred_results))
    if(int(x)==int(pred_results["classes"])): #POINT OF ERROR
        c+=1                                            ######
    print("\n")
  print(c)  
                ###
```

The idea is to get the predicted "1" stored in "classes" and compare it with its actual label.

Answer (score 0):

I converted the EstimatorSpec object to a string and then performed split on it to get the integer class_id

```
for i in range(0,len(FileList)):
    x=FileList[i].split('\\')[5]        
    print(FileList[i]+"\nProbability:")
    y=str(next(pred_results)).split(',')[0].split(":")[1].strip()
    print(y)
    if(int(x)==int(y)):#####
        c+=1                                            ######
    print("\n")
```

I'm running this snippet of code to find out how many classes have been correctly classified. Might not be optimal but will do for now.